# Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'Promise<any>' and 'string'. - Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

The error below show on my console when I was building my ionic app.

> [14:24:56]  typescript: c:/mIncident/src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 220
>               Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'Promise' and 'string'.
>        L219:  let simPermission = this.sim.requestReadPermission();
>        L220:  if (simPermission == "OK") {
>        L221:    let simData = this.sim.getSimInfo();

**.ts code**

```
let simPermission = this.sim.requestReadPermission();
if (simPermission == "OK") {
  let simData = this.sim.getSimInfo();
  this.simInfo = simData;
  //this.cards = simData.cards;


for(var i = 0; i < this.simInfo.length; i++){
this.phone = this.simInfo[i].phoneNumber;
}
  //console.log(simData);
}else{
  this.buttonDisabled = true;
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
subTitle:("You need to grant this app permission to access your sim card"),
buttons: ['OK']
});
```

What does this error means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.sim.requestReadPermission` returns a promise. So, you're trying to compare a promise to a string, which won't work.

Using the Ionic Native - Sim documentation, the following would be what you want

```
this.sim.requestReadPermission().then(
  () => {
      let simData = this.sim.getSimInfo();
      this.simInfo = simData;
      //this.cards = simData.cards;

      for(let i = 0; i < this.simInfo.length; i++){
          this.phone = this.simInfo[i].phoneNumber;
      }
     //console.log(simData);
  },
  () => {
      this.buttonDisabled = true;
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          subTitle:("You need to grant this app permission to access your sim card"),
          buttons: ['OK']
      });
  }
);
```

Note that `this.sim.getSimInfo()` is also a promise, so you'll need to do something similar for that.